# Display Views results in a specific order?

Tags: 7, views

I have a Views result set that I would like to give a very specific order not just 'ascending, descending' or defaults.

Currently I am saving them in reverse order and sorting by date updated descending, but this is somewhat of a pain.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Existing modules? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set arbitratry order on Views using the various ordering modules listed [here](http://drupal.org/node/398508).

[Draggable Views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) is probably the most popular.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471361/drupal-sorting-a-view-programmatically ;  //

_views_pre_render gives you the opportunity to reorder results